# Serialize MongoDB collection with generic attribute names

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I want to serialize a collection in MongoDB in which every document has only ONE field at a time *other than _id and timestamp*.

Only one field will have value. The others will be null/not present in the document. They are mutually exclusive.

At the moment I'm hardcoding all the possible fields in an object as follows:

```
public class Signals : DomainClassBase
{
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }

#nullable enable
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public double[]? JLVib { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public double[]? JRVib { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public double[]? YLVib { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public double[]? YRVib { get; set; }
#nullable disable
}
```

To be clear, only one of the attributes above will be in each document each time (+ the timestamp and the _id).

[image: MongoDb Collection]

Is there anyway to generalize the name of the fields?

Comment: What do you mean *a collection in MongoDB which has only ONE attribute at a time.* ? I don't get it. Please elaborate the question better!

Comment: I added a snap of the mongoDB. In each document there will be only the timestamp and one other field.

Comment: So you are saying only 1 of the 4 properties will have value, others will be null? What if more than 1 has values, you want to keep only 1? You need to explain the behaviour in words, cause this way you leave way for different interpretations...

Comment: Only one will have value. The others will be null. They are mutually exclusive.